# Grouping error with lmer

Tags: r, dataframe, lme4

I have a data frame with the following structure:

```
> t <- read.csv("combinedData.csv")[,1:7]
> str(t)
'data.frame':   699 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Awns               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ Funnel             : Factor w/ 213 levels "MEL001","MEL002",..: 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ Plant              : int  1 2 1 3 8 1 1 2 3 5 ...
 $ Line               : Factor w/ 8 levels "a","b","c","cA",..: 2 2 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ X                  : int  1 2 3 4 7 8 9 10 11 12 ...
 $ ID                 : Factor w/ 699 levels "MEL_001-1b","MEL_001-2b",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ BobWhite_c10082_241: int  2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 0 ...
```

I want to construct a mixed effect model. I know in my data frame that the random effect I want to include (Funnel) is a factor, but it does not work:

```
> lmer(t$Awns ~ (1|t$Funnel) + t$BobWhite_c10082_241)
Error: couldn't evaluate grouping factor t$Funnel within model frame: try adding grouping factor to data frame explicitly if possible
```

In fact this happens whatever I want to include as a random effect e.g. Plant:

```
> lmer(t$Awns ~ (1|t$Plant) + t$BobWhite_c10082_241)
Error: couldn't evaluate grouping factor t$Plant within model frame: try adding grouping factor to data frame explicitly if possible
```

Why is R giving me this error? The only other answer I could google fu is that the random effect fed in wasn't a factor in the DF. But as str shows, df$Funnel certainly is.

Comment: Your really, really should use the `data` parameter: `lmer(Awns ~ (1|Funnel) + BobWhite_c10082_241, data = t)` Strange things can happen if you don't follow that praxis (also with other model functions like `lm`).

Comment: That does actually completely solve it! Create an answer and I'll make it the accepted.

Comment: @Roland, please post as answer?

Comment: @BenBolker Since I'm at a conference it took me a while, but I have posted an answer. Feel free to edit it if I didn't present the perspective of a package author correctly.

Comment: looks good.  One could dig/trace through the source code to figure out *exactly* what's going wrong, but I think your answer is essentially the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is actually not so easy to provide a convenient syntax for modeling functions and at the same time have a robust implementation. Most package authors assume that you use the `data` parameter and even then scoping issues can occur. Thus, strange things can happen if you specify variables with `DF$col` syntax since package authors rarely spend a lot of effort to make this work correctly and don't include a lot of unit tests for this.

It is therefore strongly recommended to use the `data` parameter if the model function offers a `formula` method. Strange things can happen if you don't follow that praxis (also with other model functions like `lm`).

In your example:

```
lmer(Awns ~ (1|Funnel) + BobWhite_c10082_241, data = t)
```

This not only works, but is also more convenient to write.