# Lme4: error on random effect when looping glmer

Tags: r, for-loop, error-handling, lme4, random-effects

I am trying to run a loop of mixed effect models on a large number of variables.

Below, I have tested the model structure on a null model and a model with one predictor variable, and these ran with no errors or warnings

```
## Null model 
df_m0 <- glmer(pred_recent_pf_bin ~ +   (1 | houseID), data = df, family = binomial, weights = weight, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"),
            nAGQ = 10)
#test one variable
df_mtest <- glmer(pred_recent_pf_bin ~  Motorsikal + (1 | houseID), data = df, family = binomial, weights = weight, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"),
               nAGQ = 10)
```

However when I try to loop the model, I receive the following warning:

```
# set list of variables for looped model 
df_var <- df[2:253]

## Run model for all variables
for(i in 1:length(df_var)){
  
  # Set formula
  fmla <- paste0("pred_recent_pf_bin ~ + ", df_var[i], " + (1|houseID)")
  
  # Run model 
  m1 <- glmer(fmla, data = df, family = binomial, weights = weight, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"),
              nAGQ = 10)
}

Error: couldn't evaluate grouping factor houseID within model frame: try adding grouping factor to data frame explicitly if possible
```

HouseID is set as a factor, with 2849 levels

From what I can see from a similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650695/grouping-error-with-lmer) and [here](http://r-sig-ecology.471788.n2.nabble.com/Problem-with-glmm-with-nested-random-effects-td7579602.html), this can be due to the model missing the data parameter, but I have been sure to include it in my model. Other reports of this error appear to be with nested random effects, but I only have one.

Minimal reproducible answer with data, giving the same error:

```
library(lme4)

#take subset of df dataset
rep <- subset(df, select = c("houseID", "pred_recent_pf_bin", "weight", "smoke", "Motorsikal", "X100m__slopemean", "ac200pa"))

#set list of variables for looped models
rep_vars <- rep[4:7]

#run model for all variables 
for(i in 1:length(rep_vars)){
  
  # Set formula
  fmla <- paste0("pred_recent_pf_bin ~ +  ", rep_vars[i], " + (1|houseID)")
  
  # Run model 
  m1 <- glmer(fmla, data = rep, family = binomial, weights = weight, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"),
              nAGQ = 10)
}
Error: couldn't evaluate grouping factor houseID within model frame: try adding grouping factor to data frame explicitly if possible
```

```
> dput(rep[1:6,])
structure(list(houseID = structure(c(644L, 2191L, 823L, 821L, 
368L, 1274L), .Label = c("AB006", "AB009", "AB018", "AB027", 
"AB038", "AB042", "AB043", "AB044", "AB045", "AB046", "AB050", 
"AB051", "AB052", "AB057", "AB059", "AB060", "AB061", "AB064", 
"AB068", "AB072", "AB075", "AJ001", "AJ003", "AJ004", "AJ005", 
"AJ006", "AJ009", "AJ010", "AJ011", "AJ012", "AJ013", "AJ014", 
"AJ015", "AJ016", "AJ018", "AJ020", "BA002", "BA003", "BA007", 
"BA009", "BA010", "BA012", "BA014", "BA015", "BA016", "BA017", 
"BA018", "BA020", "BA026", "BA027", "BA029", "BA032", "BA033", 
"BA034", "BA039", "BA041", "BA042", "BB002", "BB003", "BB004", 
"BB005", "BB008", "BB009", "BB010", "BB011", "BB012", "BB014", 
"BB017", "BB019", "BB020", "BB021", "BB022", "BB025", "BB026", 
"BB027", "BB028", "BB029", "BB030", "BC004", "BC009", "BC010", 
"BC011", "BC012", "BC013", "BC014", "BC015", "BC016", "BC022", 
"BC023", "BC025", "BC026", "BC027", "BC028", "BC029", "BC030", 
"BC034", "BC037", "BC040", "BC041", "BD001", "BD003", "BD004", 
"BD008", "BD009", "BD013", "BD015", "BD016", "BD017", "BD020", 
"BD022", "BD023", "BD024", "BD026", "BD027", "BD029", "BD030", 
"BD031", "BE001", "BE002", "BE004", "BE005", "BE006", "BE007", 
"BE008", "BE009", "BE010", "BE014", "BE015", "BE018", "BE019", 
"BE020", "BE021", "BE023", "BE024", "BE025", "BE026", "BE028", 
"BE029", "BE032", "BE033", "BE034", "BE035", "BE037", "BE038", 
"BG002", "BG003", "BG004", "BG005", "BG008", "BG009", "BG010", 
"BG011", "BG012", "BG013", "BG015", "BG016", "BG018", "BG019", 
"BG020", "BG022", "BG023", "BG024", "BG026", "BH001", "BH002", 
"BH003", "BH004", "BH006", "BH007", "BH008", "BH009", "BH010", 
"BH012", "BH016", "BH018", "BH019", "BH020", "BH026", "BH028", 
"BH030", "BH031", "BH032", "BH033", "BI001", "BI005", "BI006", 
"BI009", "BI013", "BI022", "BI024", "BI025", "BI031", "BI033", 
"BI036", "BI043", "BI046", "BI050", "BI052", "BI059", "BI061", 
"BI066", "BI067", "BI073", "BJ002", "BJ003", "BJ006", "BJ007", 
"BJ009", "BJ010", "BJ014", "BJ015", "BJ016", "BJ019", "BJ037", 
"BJ039", "BJ044", "BJ045", "BJ046", "BJ047", "BJ048", "BJ049", 
"BJ051", "BK001", "BK005", "BK006", "BK007", "BK008", "BK009", 
"BK010", "BK011", "BK012", "BM001", "BM002", "BM003", "BM004", 
"BM005", "BM007", "BM008", "BM009", "BM011", "BM013", "BM014", 
"BM015", "BM016", "BM017", "BM018", "BM019", "BM020", "BM022", 
"BM023", "BM024", "BO002", "BO004", "BO005", "BO006", "BO007", 
"BO008", "BO009", "BO012", "BO013", "BO014", "BO015", "BO016", 
"BO017", "BP003", "BP004", "BP005", "BP006", "BP008", "BP009", 
"BP010", "BP012", "BP014", "BP016", "BP017", "BP019", "BP020", 
"BP021", "BP022", "BP024", "BP025", "BP026", "BP028", "BP030", 
"BP031", "BR001", "BR002", "BR004", "BR005", "BR007", "BR008", 
"BR009", "BR012", "BR015", "BR017", "BR023", "BR026", "BR028", 
"BR030", "BR031", "BR032", "BR033", "BR034", "BR036", "BR037", 
"BS001", "BS002", "BS004", "BS005", "BS007", "BS011", "BS012", 
"BS013", "BS020", "BS021", "BS023", "BS024", "BS034", "BS035", 
"BS036", "BS037", "BS039", "BS040", "BS044", "BS046", "BS048", 
"BT001", "BT002", "BT003", "BT004", "BT005", "BT006", "BU001", 
"BU002", "BU003", "BU004", "BU005", "BU009", "BU012", "BU013", 
"BW001", "BW002", "BW005", "BW007", "BW008", "BW009", "BW010", 
"BW011", "BW012", "BW013", "BW014", "BW015", "BW016", "BW017", 
"BW018", "BX014", "BX015", "BX022", "BX055", "BX057", "BX082", 
"BX083", "BX097", "BX099", "BX110", "BX111", "BX113", "BX118", 
"BX119", "BX121", "BX122", "BZ001", "BZ002", "BZ004", "BZ005", 
"BZ006", "BZ007", "BZ008", "BZ009", "BZ010", "BZ011", "BZ012", 
"BZ013", "BZ014", "DA008", "DA012", "DA027", "DA034", "DA035", 
"DA039", "DA040", "DA055", "DA064", "DA065", "DA066", "DA071", 
"DA078", "DA089", "DA103", "DA105", "DA113", "DA123", "DA130", 
"DA139", "DB001", "DB002", "DB004", "DB006", "DB012", "DB017", 
"DB025", "DB028", "DB039", "DB041", "DB045", "DB048", "DB049", 
"DB053", "DL003", "DL004", "DL005", "DL007", "DL008", "DL012", 
"DL013", "DL014", "DL016", "DL017", "DL018", "DL019", "DL020", 
"DL021", "DL022", "DU005", "DU008", "DU010", "DU011", "DU013", 
"DU018", "DU020", "DU021", "DU022", "DU029", "DU032", "DU033", 
"DU036", "DU043", "DU045", "DU048", "DU049", "GA002", "GA005", 
"GA006", "GA007", "GA008", "GA009", "GA010", "GA011", "GA013", 
"GA015", "GA016", "GA017", "GA023", "GA024", "GA026", "GA027", 
"GL001", "GL002", "GL003", "GL019", "GL020", "GL021", "GL022", 
"GL023", "GL024", "GL026", "GL028", "GL029", "GL030", "GO001", 
"GO005", "GO007", "GO008", "GO009", "GO013", "GO015", "GO016", 
"GO018", "GO019", "GO023", "GO025", "GO028", "GO029", "GO030", 
"GO032", "GO034", "GO037", "GO038", "GO039", "GP001", "GP002", 
"GP003", "GP004", "GP005", "GP006", "GP007", "GP008", "GP009", 
"GP010", "GP011", "GP014", "GP015", "GP016", "GP017", "GP019", 
"GR001", "GR002", "GR003", "GR004", "GR007", "GR008", "GR009", 
"GR010", "GR011", "GR012", "GR013", "GR014", "GR015", "GR016", 
"GR017", "GR018", "GR020", "GR021", "GX001", "GX002", "GX003", 
"GX004", "KA005", "KA007", "KA008", "KA009", "KA010", "KA017", 
"KA018", "KA019", "KA020", "KA021", "KA022", "KA026", "KA028", 
"KA031", "KA033", "KA034", "KA036", "KA040", "KA041", "KA045", 
"KB001", "KB002", "KB003", "KB004", "KB005", "KB006", "KB007", 
"KB008", "KB009", "KB010", "KB012", "KB013", "KB014", "KB015", 
"KB016", "KB017", "KB018", "KB019", "KC002", "KC003", "KC004", 
"KC005", "KC006", "KC008", "KC010", "KC013", "KC015", "KC020", 
"KC021", "KC022", "KC023", "KC024", "KC025", "KC026", "KC027", 
"KC042", "KC045", "KC049", "KC053", "KC055", "KC056", "KC058", 
"KD001", "KD002", "KD003", "KD005", "KD007", "KD008", "KD020", 
"KD021", "KD022", "KD027", "KD029", "KD030", "KD032", "KD038", 
"KD040", "KD041", "KD042", "KD044", "KD045", "KD046", "KE001", 
"KE002", "KE003", "KE004", "KE005", "KE006", "KE007", "KE008", 
"KE009", "KE010", "KE011", "KE012", "KE013", "KE014", "KE015", 
"KE016", "KE017", "KE018", "KF001", "KF002", "KF003", "KF004", 
"KF005", "KF006", "KF007", "KF008", "KF009", "KF010", "KF011", 
"KF012", "KF014", "KF015", "KF016", "KF017", "KF018", "KF019", 
"KF020", "KF021", "KF023", "KG001", "KG003", "KG004", "KG005", 
"KG006", "KG007", "KG009", "KG010", "KG011", "KG012", "KG013", 
"KG014", "KG015", "KG017", "KG018", "KG019", "KG020", "KG021", 
"KG022", "KI001", "KI002", "KI004", "KI005", "KI007", "KI010", 
"KI011", "KI012", "KI013", "KI014", "KI015", "KK001", "KK004", 
"KK006", "KK009", "KK010", "KK011", "KK013", "KK014", "KK015", 
"KK016", "KK017", "KK018", "KK020", "KK022", "KK026", "KK028", 
"KK033", "KK034", "KK035", "KK036", "KK037", "KL001", "KL003", 
"KL005", "KL008", "KL010", "KL014", "KL015", "KL017", "KL018", 
"KL021", "KL024", "KL026", "KL027", "KL029", "KL036", "KL040", 
"KL043", "KL045", "KL047", "KM007", "KM008", "KM009", "KM012", 
"KM013", "KM015", "KM017", "KM019", "KM020", "KM021", "KM024", 
"KM025", "KM027", "KM029", "KM031", "KM034", "KM036", "KM037", 
"KM039", "KM040", "KN001", "KN004", "KN005", "KN007", "KN008", 
"KN009", "KN011", "KN013", "KN014", "KN015", "KN016", "KN017", 
"KN018", "KN020", "KP002", "KP003", "KP012", "KP020", "KP042", 
"KP043", "KP047", "KP054", "KP064", "KP065", "KP075", "KP078", 
"KP081", "KR001", "KR002", "KR003", "KR004", "KR005", "KR007", 
"KR008", "KR009", "KR010", "KR011", "KR013", "KR014", "KR016", 
"KR018", "KR022", "KR023", "KR024", "KR029", "KR030", "KR032", 
"KT001", "KT002", "KT003", "KT004", "KT005", "KT006", "KT007", 
"KT008", "KT010", "KT011", "KT012", "KT013", "KT014", "KT015", 
"KT016", "KT017", "KT018", "KT019", "KT020", "KU001", "KU002", 
"KU004", "KU007", "KU011", "KU012", "KU014", "KU015", "KU016", 
"KU018", "KU019", "KU027", "KU028", "KU030", "KU031", "KU034", 
"KU035", "KW004", "KW005", "KW006", "KW007", "KW008", "KW009", 
"KW010", "KW012", "KW013", "KW014", "KW015", "KW017", "KW018", 
"KW019", "KW020", "KW022", "KW024", "KW026", "KW028", "KX004", 
"KX006", "KX007", "KX009", "KX010", "KX011", "KX012", "KX022", 
"KX024", "KX027", "KX029", "KX031", "KX033", "KX034", "KX036", 
"KX037", "KX038", "KX043", "KY001", "KY002", "KY004", "KY005", 
"KY006", "KY007", "KY008", "KY009", "KY010", "KY011", "KY012", 
"KY013", "KY014", "KY015", "LA001", "LA003", "LA012", "LA013", 
"LA016", "LA017", "LA027", "LA028", "LA029", "LA030", "LA032", 
"LA037", "LA039", "LA043", "LB001", "LB003", "LB004", "LB007", 
"LB008", "LB010", "LB011", "LB012", "LB013", "LB014", "LB015", 
"LB016", "LB017", "LB018", "LB019", "LC002", "LC004", "LC005", 
"LC006", "LC007", "LC008", "LC009", "LC010", "LC011", "LC012", 
"LC013", "LC015", "LC016", "LD006", "LD012", "LD014", "LD016", 
"LD023", "LD026", "LD027", "LD029", "LD031", "LD034", "LD036", 
"LD037", "LD038", "LD039", "LD041", "LD042", "LD051", "LD052", 
"LE003", "LE004", "LE005", "LE006", "LE007", "LE008", "LE012", 
"LE013", "LE016", "LE017", "LE019", "LE021", "LE022", "LE023", 
"LE024", "LE027", "LE028", "LE029", "LE030", "LE031", "LG004", 
"LG008", "LG012", "LG016", "LG017", "LG018", "LG019", "LG023", 
"LG024", "LG026", "LG027", "LG029", "LG030", "LG035", "LG036", 
"LG037", "LG044", "LG047", "LI002", "LI005", "LI006", "LI009", 
"LI010", "LI012", "LI014", "LI016", "LI019", "LI023", "LI024", 
"LI026", "LI027", "LI029", "LI037", "LI038", "LI040", "LI043", 
"LI044", "LI046", "LI054", "LI057", "LJ001", "LJ002", "LJ003", 
"LJ012", "LJ015", "LJ016", "LJ018", "LJ020", "LJ025", "LJ028", 
"LJ039", "LJ041", "LJ044", "LJ047", "LJ048", "LJ051", "LJ056", 
"LJ061", "LJ066", "LK001", "LK002", "LL003", "LL004", "LL006", 
"LL008", "LL010", "LL011", "LL012", "LL015", "LL016", "LL022", 
"LL024", "LL025", "LL027", "LL029", "LL030", "LL035", "LL036", 
"LL038", "LM001", "LM002", "LM003", "LM005", "LM006", "LM007", 
"LM010", "LM011", "LM013", "LM015", "LM016", "LM017", "LM018", 
"LN001", "LN004", "LN006", "LN008", "LN010", "LN011", "LN012", 
"LN013", "LN014", "LN016", "LN018", "LN019", "LN022", "LN023", 
"LN026", "LN028", "LN030", "LN032", "LN033", "LN034", "LN035", 
"LO003", "LO005", "LO008", "LO010", "LO012", "LO014", "LO015", 
"LO017", "LO018", "LO019", "LO020", "LO022", "LO023", "LO024", 
"LO026", "LO028", "LO030", "LO031", "LP001", "LP002", "LP006", 
"LP007", "LP008", "LP013", "LP014", "LP016", "LP020", "LP021", 
"LP024", "LP026", "LP029", "LP030", "LP033", "LP034", "LP035", 
"LP037", "LP043", "LR002", "LR005", "LR007", "LR010", "LR012", 
"LR013", "LR014", "LR015", "LR017", "LR020", "LR021", "LR022", 
"LR024", "LR025", "LR026", "LR030", "LR031", "LR033", "LR034", 
"LR036", "LS002", "LS004", "LS005", "LS006", "LS007", "LS008", 
"LS009", "LS010", "LS012", "LS013", "LS014", "LS015", "LS016", 
"LS018", "LS020", "LS021", "LS022", "LS023", "LS027", "LS028", 
"LT001", "LT003", "LT005", "LT008", "LT009", "LT011", "LT012", 
"LT022", "LT023", "LT024", "LT025", "LT027", "LX002", "LX004", 
"LX005", "LX006", "LX007", "LX008", "LX009", "LX010", "LX011", 
"LX013", "LX015", "LX016", "LX017", "LX018", "LX019", "LX020", 
"LX021", "LX022", "LX024", "LX028", "LY001", "LY002", "LY005", 
"LY006", "LY008", "LY009", "LY010", "LY015", "LY018", "LY019", 
"LY020", "LY021", "LY024", "LY025", "LY026", "LY027", "LY028", 
"LY029", "LZ001", "LZ002", "LZ003", "LZ004", "LZ005", "LZ006", 
"LZ007", "LZ008", "LZ009", "LZ010", "LZ011", "LZ012", "MA004", 
"MA006", "MA007", "MA008", "MA011", "MA012", "MA014", "MA017", 
"MA018", "MA020", "MA021", "MA022", "MA023", "MA024", "MA025", 
"MA026", "MA027", "MA028", "MA031", "MA032", "MB001", "MB002", 
"MB004", "MB006", "MB007", "MB009", "MB010", "MB011", "MB014", 
"MB016", "MB017", "MB018", "MB019", "MB020", "MB021", "MB022", 
"MB023", "MC002", "MC005", "MC006", "MC007", "MC010", "MC012", 
"MC013", "MC014", "MC015", "MC016", "MC017", "MC018", "MC021", 
"MC027", "MC029", "MC030", "MC035", "MC036", "MD004", "MD007", 
"MD009", "MD016", "MD017", "MD024", "MD025", "MD028", "MD032", 
"MD034", "MD037", "MD038", "MD044", "MD047", "MD050", "MD052", 
"MD053", "MD054", "MD056", "MD058", "ME005", "ME016", "ME017", 
"ME027", "ME029", "ME032", "ME039", "ME041", "ME044", "ME048", 
"ME051", "ME055", "ME056", "ME059", "ME060", "ME061", "ME062", 
"ME068", "ME069", "MF001", "MF002", "MF005", "MF008", "MF009", 
"MF013", "MF014", "MF015", "MF016", "MF017", "MF018", "MF021", 
"MF022", "MF023", "MF024", "MF026", "MF027", "MF028", "MF029", 
"MF030", "MF033", "MF037", "MF041", "MF043", "MF044", "MF047", 
"MF048", "MF049", "MF050", "MF111", "MF222", "MF333", "MG001", 
"MG005", "MG008", "MG015", "MG019", "MG020", "MG021", "MG023", 
"MG024", "MG029", "MG031", "MG033", "MG036", "MG037", "MG039", 
"MG040", "MG041", "MG047", "MG048", "MG050", "MG051", "MH001", 
"MH003", "MH004", "MH005", "MI001", "MI002", "MI003", "MI004", 
"MI005", "MI006", "MI008", "MI009", "MI010", "MI011", "MI012", 
"MI013", "MI014", "MI015", "MI016", "MI017", "MI018", "MI019", 
"MI020", "MK002", "MK003", "MK006", "MK007", "MK008", "MK009", 
"MK010", "MK011", "MK020", "MK022", "MK023", "MK024", "MK025", 
"MK026", "MK027", "MK028", "MK029", "MK030", "MK031", "MK034", 
"ML001", "ML007", "ML010", "ML012", "ML015", "ML016", "ML019", 
"ML021", "ML022", "ML024", "ML027", "ML032", "ML034", "ML036", 
"ML037", "ML043", "ML044", "ML047", "ML052", "ML053", "MM004", 
"MM005", "MM007", "MM008", "MM011", "MM013", "MM014", "MM015", 
"MM016", "MM018", "MM019", "MM020", "MM021", "MM022", "MM023", 
"MM027", "MM028", "MM029", "MN001", "MN003", "MN004", "MN005", 
"MN008", "MN010", "MN011", "MN012", "MN014", "MN016", "MN017", 
"MN018", "MN020", "MN022", "MN024", "MN031", "MN033", "MN034", 
"MN035", "MN039", "MN044", "MN045", "MN048", "MN051", "MN057", 
"MN059", "MP003", "MP006", "MP008", "MP015", "MP018", "MP029", 
"MP043", "MP044", "MP046", "MP047", "MP049", "MP050", "MP067", 
"MP089", "MP091", "MP097", "MP105", "MP109", "MQ004", "MQ005", 
"MQ007", "MQ010", "MQ013", "MQ015", "MQ018", "MQ022", "MQ025", 
"MQ027", "MQ028", "MQ030", "MQ032", "MQ035", "MQ040", "MQ044", 
"MQ045", "MQ048", "MQ049", "MQ051", "MR006", "MR008", "MR016", 
"MR017", "MR018", "MR019", "MR025", "MR026", "MR035", "MR038", 
"MR039", "MR041", "MU005", "MU007", "MU008", "MU010", "MU012", 
"MU014", "MU016", "MU018", "MU024", "MU025", "MU028", "MU029", 
"MU033", "MU038", "MU046", "MX002", "MX003", "MX004", "MX005", 
"MX006", "MX007", "MX008", "MX009", "MX010", "MX011", "MX012", 
"MX013", "MX014", "NA001", "NA004", "NA006", "NA010", "NA012", 
"NA014", "NA016", "NA017", "NA019", "NA020", "NA022", "NA025", 
"NA026", "NA028", "NA029", "NA030", "NA032", "NA033", "NA036", 
"NA041", "NB002", "NB008", "NB011", "NB012", "NB013", "NB015", 
"NB022", "NB025", "NB029", "NB032", "NB037", "ND001", "ND002", 
"ND003", "ND006", "ND009", "ND010", "ND011", "ND012", "ND013", 
"ND014", "ND015", "ND019", "ND020", "ND021", "ND022", "ND024", 
"ND025", "ND026", "ND027", "ND028", "ND030", "NP002", "NP005", 
"NP007", "NP011", "NP012", "NP013", "NP017", "NP022", "NP023", 
"NP029", "NP030", "NP031", "NP033", "NP034", "NP035", "NP037", 
"NU001", "NU004", "NU006", "NU009", "NU010", "NU011", "NU012", 
"NU014", "NU016", "NU017", "PA002", "PA005", "PA006", "PA007", 
"PA008", "PA009", "PA010", "PA011", "PA012", "PA014", "PA016", 
"PA017", "PA018", "PA019", "PB001", "PB002", "PB003", "PB004", 
"PB005", "PB006", "PB008", "PB009", "PB012", "PB013", "PB014", 
"PB015", "PB016", "PB017", "PB019", "PB021", "PB022", "PB023", 
"PB025", "PB026", "PC001", "PC016", "PC017", "PC018", "PC019", 
"PC020", "PC021", "PC022", "PC023", "PC025", "PC027", "PC035", 
"PC039", "PC041", "PC048", "PC052", "PC056", "PC061", "PC063", 
"PD001", "PD002", "PD003", "PD004", "PD005", "PD006", "PD007", 
"PD010", "PD013", "PD014", "PD016", "PD017", "PD020", "PD022", 
"PD023", "PD024", "PD025", "PD026", "PE001", "PE002", "PE003", 
"PE004", "PE005", "PE007", "PE009", "PE010", "PE014", "PE015", 
"PE016", "PE017", "PE019", "PE020", "PE022", "PE023", "PE026", 
"PE027", "PG001", "PG004", "PG017", "PG020", "PG023", "PG026", 
"PG040", "PG041", "PG043", "PG044", "PG046", "PG049", "PH004", 
"PH005", "PI001", "PI002", "PI003", "PI005", "PI014", "PI016", 
"PI023", "PI027", "PI029", "PI035", "PI036", "PK001", "PK003", 
"PK004", "PK005", "PK006", "PK009", "PK010", "PK011", "PK012", 
"PK013", "PK015", "PK016", "PK017", "PK018", "PK019", "PK021", 
"PK022", "PL002", "PL003", "PL005", "PL006", "PL007", "PL009", 
"PL010", "PL011", "PL012", "PL013", "PM007", "PM009", "PM012", 
"PM013", "PM014", "PM018", "PM021", "PM024", "PM025", "PM027", 
"PM029", "PM031", "PM032", "PM038", "PM041", "PM043", "PM044", 
"PM045", "PM046", "PN001", "PN002", "PN004", "PN007", "PN008", 
"PN009", "PN012", "PN015", "PN016", "PN018", "PN019", "PN020", 
"PN023", "PN024", "PN034", "PN037", "PN038", "PN042", "PN043", 
"PO001", "PO004", "PO006", "PO010", "PO012", "PO021", "PO029", 
"PO033", "PO036", "PO038", "PO043", "PO044", "PO045", "PO049", 
"PO052", "PO055", "PO058", "PO061", "PO070", "PP002", "PP003", 
"PP004", "PP005", "PP006", "PP007", "PP008", "PP009", "PP010", 
"PP011", "PP012", "PP013", "PP014", "PP015", "PP016", "PP017", 
"PP020", "PP022", "PP023", "PR002", "PR004", "PR005", "PR009", 
"PR012", "PR014", "PR017", "PR018", "PR020", "PR021", "PR027", 
"PR028", "PR034", "PR035", "PR038", "PR039", "PR043", "PR044", 
"PR046", "PS001", "PS002", "PS003", "PS008", "PS009", "PS010", 
"PS011", "PS013", "PS016", "PS019", "PS020", "PS021", "PS023", 
"PS024", "PS026", "PS027", "PS028", "PS030", "PS031", "PS032", 
"PT001", "PT004", "PT007", "PT010", "PT011", "PT013", "PT014", 
"PT015", "PT016", "PT017", "PT022", "PT028", "PT029", "PT031", 
"PT032", "PT033", "PT035", "PT036", "PT037", "PU001", "PU002", 
"PU003", "PU005", "PU006", "PU007", "PU008", "PU009", "PU010", 
"PW002", "PW003", "PW007", "PW011", "PW012", "PW017", "PW018", 
"PW019", "PW020", "PW021", "PW024", "PW026", "PW031", "PW033", 
"PW038", "PW043", "PW050", "PW062", "PW068", "PX001", "PX003", 
"PX005", "PX006", "PX007", "PX008", "PX009", "PX010", "PX012", 
"PX014", "PX015", "PX016", "PX017", "RB002", "RB004", "RB006", 
"RB007", "RB008", "RB012", "RB013", "RB014", "RB015", "RB017", 
"RB018", "RB021", "RB022", "RB026", "RB027", "RB032", "RB033", 
"RB034", "RB035", "RB037", "RG001", "RG003", "RG007", "RG009", 
"RG010", "RG012", "RG013", "RG014", "RG015", "RG016", "RG017", 
"RG018", "RG021", "RG022", "RG023", "RG024", "RG025", "RG026", 
"RG027", "RG028", "RG029", "RK002", "RK003", "RK004", "RK005", 
"RK012", "RK013", "RK018", "RK019", "RK020", "RK022", "RK024", 
"RK026", "RK027", "RK028", "RK029", "RK030", "RK032", "RK036", 
"RK038", "RK039", "RK041", "RM001", "RM003", "RM005", "RM007", 
"RM009", "RM010", "RM011", "RM012", "RM013", "RM015", "RM016", 
"RM017", "RM018", "RM019", "RM020", "RM021", "RU001", "RU002", 
"RU004", "RU007", "RU008", "RU011", "RU014", "RU015", "RU016", 
"RU017", "RU020", "RU021", "RU022", "RU024", "RU025", "RU026", 
"RU027", "RU028", "SA001", "SA004", "SA005", "SA006", "SA007", 
"SA009", "SA014", "SA016", "SA017", "SA021", "SA024", "SA027", 
"SA028", "SA029", "SA031", "SA045", "SA047", "SA052", "SA058", 
"SA059", "SA069", "SA070", "SB001", "SB004", "SB012", "SB013", 
"SB015", "SB016", "SB018", "SB019", "SB021", "SB022", "SB023", 
"SB024", "SB029", "SB030", "SB033", "SB034", "SB035", "SB037", 
"SB040", "SC001", "SC002", "SC005", "SC006", "SC008", "SC015", 
"SC017", "SC018", "SC022", "SD004", "SD005", "SD010", "SD015", 
"SD016", "SD018", "SD023", "SE006", "SE013", "SE014", "SE015", 
"SE016", "SE017", "SE018", "SE019", "SE020", "SE021", "SF002", 
"SF003", "SF005", "SF007", "SF009", "SF010", "SF011", "SF012", 
"SF013", "SF018", "SF020", "SF024", "SF026", "SF029", "SF031", 
"SF034", "SF035", "SG001", "SG002", "SG005", "SG006", "SG007", 
"SG011", "SG012", "SG013", "SG014", "SG016", "SG018", "SG019", 
"SG024", "SG025", "SG027", "SG031", "SG033", "SG035", "SG036", 
"SG038", "SH004", "SH005", "SH006", "SH008", "SH010", "SH014", 
"SH016", "SH019", "SH023", "SH024", "SH025", "SH026", "SH027", 
"SH028", "SH030", "SH031", "SI007", "SI015", "SI016", "SI046", 
"SI047", "SI053", "SI059", "SI060", "SI076", "SI079", "SI080", 
"SI085", "SI093", "SI094", "SI098", "SI109", "SI124", "SJ002", 
"SJ003", "SJ009", "SJ014", "SJ015", "SJ018", "SJ021", "SJ022", 
"SJ024", "SJ028", "SJ029", "SJ033", "SJ038", "SJ039", "SJ040", 
"SJ044", "SJ045", "SK008", "SK011", "SK013", "SK018", "SK024", 
"SK028", "SK029", "SK033", "SK034", "SK036", "SK039", "SK041", 
"SK043", "SK046", "SK047", "SK049", "SK052", "SK058", "SK059", 
"SK060", "SL001", "SL003", "SL005", "SM002", "SM004", "SM007", 
"SM008", "SM010", "SM011", "SM016", "SM017", "SM018", "SM019", 
"SM020", "SM021", "SM022", "SM023", "SM025", "SM026", "SN001", 
"SN002", "SN005", "SN006", "SN008", "SN009", "SN010", "SN013", 
"SN014", "SN015", "SN016", "SN017", "SN018", "SN021", "SN025", 
"SN026", "SN027", "SN028", "SN029", "SO001", "SO010", "SO011", 
"SO013", "SO014", "SO016", "SO017", "SO022", "SO024", "SO027", 
"SO028", "SO030", "SO033", "SO046", "SO047", "SP001", "SP003", 
"SP004", "SP006", "SP007", "SQ001", "SQ002", "SQ003", "SQ004", 
"SQ005", "SQ006", "SQ007", "SQ008", "SQ009", "SQ010", "SQ011", 
"SQ012", "SR001", "SR002", "SR003", "SR004", "SR006", "SR007", 
"SR008", "SR009", "SR010", "SR011", "SR013", "SR015", "SR016", 
"SR017", "SR018", "SR019", "SR021", "SR022", "SR024", "SS001", 
"SS003", "SS012", "SS013", "SS014", "SS016", "SS023", "SS024", 
"SS026", "SS027", "SS030", "SS031", "SS035", "SS036", "SS041", 
"ST004", "ST005", "ST010", "ST012", "ST013", "ST020", "ST022", 
"ST025", "ST026", "SU001", "SU002", "SU003", "SU004", "SU006", 
"SU007", "SU008", "SU009", "SU010", "SU012", "SU013", "SU014", 
"SU015", "SV001", "SV003", "SV004", "SV005", "SV006", "SV008", 
"SV010", "SV011", "SV012", "SV014", "SV015", "SV016", "SV017", 
"SV019", "SV020", "SV021", "SV022", "SV023", "SV024", "SV025", 
"SW001", "SW002", "SW003", "SW005", "SW006", "SW007", "SW008", 
"SW009", "SW010", "SW011", "SW012", "SW013", "SW014", "SW015", 
"SW016", "SW018", "SW019", "SW021", "SW022", "SX002", "SX003", 
"SX004", "SX005", "SX006", "SX007", "SX008", "SX009", "SX010", 
"SX012", "SX013", "SX015", "SX016", "SX017", "SX018", "SX019", 
"SX020", "SX023", "SY001", "SY002", "SY011", "SY013", "SY014", 
"SY015", "SY018", "SY024", "SY025", "SY029", "SY031", "SY034", 
"SY035", "SY036", "SY040", "SY041", "SY046", "SY048", "SY053", 
"SY059", "SZ001", "SZ002", "SZ004", "SZ006", "SZ009", "SZ011", 
"SZ012", "SZ013", "SZ014", "SZ015", "SZ016", "SZ017", "SZ018", 
"SZ019", "SZ020", "SZ021", "SZ025", "TA002", "TA003", "TA004", 
"TA005", "TA007", "TA008", "TA009", "TA011", "TA012", "TA013", 
"TA014", "TA015", "TA016", "TA017", "TA018", "TA019", "TA021", 
"TA022", "TA023", "TB001", "TB002", "TB003", "TB004", "TB006", 
"TB010", "TB012", "TB013", "TB014", "TB015", "TB016", "TB017", 
"TB018", "TB019", "TB021", "TB023", "TC009", "TC010", "TC011", 
"TC012", "TC013", "TC016", "TC017", "TD003", "TD006", "TD012", 
"TD014", "TD015", "TD016", "TD017", "TD019", "TD020", "TD024", 
"TD026", "TD027", "TD029", "TD032", "TD033", "TD035", "TD040", 
"TD041", "TD042", "TE001", "TE003", "TE007", "TE008", "TE010", 
"TE021", "TE022", "TE026", "TE027", "TE031", "TE033", "TE039", 
"TE040", "TE047", "TE052", "TE059", "TE069", "TE072", "TE074", 
"TF002", "TF006", "TF012", "TF018", "TF020", "TF025", "TF028", 
"TF032", "TF034", "TF043", "TF049", "TF052", "TF053", "TF054", 
"TF055", "TF058", "TF060", "TG005", "TG006", "TG007", "TG012", 
"TG018", "TG019", "TG020", "TG023", "TG025", "TG033", "TG034", 
"TG035", "TG048", "TG049", "TG055", "TG056", "TH003", "TH005", 
"TH006", "TH007", "TH008", "TH009", "TH011", "TH013", "TH014", 
"TH015", "TH017", "TH020", "TH024", "TI001", "TI002", "TI003", 
"TI005", "TI007", "TI008", "TI011", "TI013", "TI015", "TI017", 
"TI018", "TI019", "TI020", "TI021", "TI022", "TI025", "TI028", 
"TI030", "TI031", "TI034", "TI035", "TI036", "TI037", "TI039", 
"TI040", "TI041", "TI042", "TI043", "TJ002", "TJ003", "TJ004", 
"TJ009", "TJ010", "TJ013", "TJ019", "TJ020", "TJ023", "TJ026", 
"TJ029", "TJ038", "TJ040", "TJ045", "TJ047", "TJ051", "TJ052", 
"TL002", "TL003", "TL004", "TL006", "TL007", "TL008", "TL009", 
"TL010", "TL011", "TL013", "TL014", "TL015", "TL016", "TL018", 
"TL019", "TL020", "TL021", "TM002", "TM003", "TM004", "TM006", 
"TM007", "TM011", "TM012", "TM014", "TM018", "TM019", "TM020", 
"TM021", "TM022", "TM023", "TM027", "TM028", "TM029", "TM030", 
"TM031", "TN006", "TN008", "TN009", "TN011", "TN013", "TN017", 
"TN020", "TN023", "TN024", "TN028", "TN031", "TN033", "TN035", 
"TN039", "TN053", "TN054", "TN059", "TN062", "TO001", "TO002", 
"TO003", "TO005", "TO006", "TO008", "TO009", "TO010", "TO011", 
"TO012", "TO013", "TO014", "TO015", "TO016", "TO018", "TO019", 
"TP001", "TP003", "TP004", "TP005", "TP006", "TP008", "TP010", 
"TP011", "TP012", "TP015", "TP016", "TP017", "TP019", "TP020", 
"TP025", "TP041", "TP044", "TP055", "TR002", "TR003", "TR008", 
"TR011", "TR012", "TR013", "TR018", "TR020", "TR023", "TR024", 
"TR027", "TR028", "TR029", "TR031", "TR032", "TR033", "TR040", 
"TR043", "TR044", "TR047", "TS001", "TS002", "TS003", "TS005", 
"TS007", "TS015", "TS017", "TT001", "TT002", "TT003", "TT005", 
"TT006", "TT007", "TT008", "TT009", "TT010", "TT011", "TU002", 
"TU003", "TU004", "TU006", "TU007", "TU010", "TU012", "TU015", 
"TU017", "TU018", "TU021", "TU024", "TU026", "TU033", "TU036", 
"TU037", "TU038", "TU039", "TU041", "TU044", "TW001", "TW002", 
"TW003", "TW005", "TW007", "TW009", "TW010", "TX001", "TX002", 
"TX005", "TX012", "TX018", "TX019", "TX025", "TX027", "TX028", 
"TX033", "TX035", "TX036", "TX040", "TX041", "TX042", "TX044", 
"TX047", "US002", "US003", "US009", "US011", "US015", "US016", 
"US018", "US020", "US021", "US023", "US027", "US029", "US030", 
"US031", "US034", "US035", "US036", "US038", "WA008", "WA009", 
"WA018", "WA019", "WA021", "WA026", "WA028", "WA029", "WA039", 
"WA043", "WA049", "WA053", "WA054", "WA058", "WA060", "WA062", 
"WA068", "WA069", "WA072", "WA076", "WA077", "WA079", "WG001", 
"WG002", "WG007", "WG008", "WG009", "WG013", "WG016", "WG017", 
"WG019", "WG020", "WG021", "WG022", "WG023", "WG026", "WG028", 
"WG029", "WG032", "WG034", "WG036", "WG037", "WG043", "WL001", 
"WL002", "WL003", "WL005", "WL006", "WL007", "WL008", "WL009", 
"WL010", "WL011", "WL012", "WL013", "WL014", "WL015", "WL016", 
"WL017", "WL018", "WL019"), class = "factor"), pred_recent_pf_bin = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    weight = c(1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2), smoke = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("FALSE", "TRUE"), class = "factor"), 
    Motorsikal = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), X100m__slopemean = c(-0.0255895725057277, 
    -1.08949221424853, -0.809496920233557, -1.0486043943469, 
    -0.799390887160726, 0.255158983311231), ac200pa = c(-0.121035991288976, 
    -0.121035991288976, -0.121035991288976, -0.121035991288976, 
    -0.121035991288976, -0.121035991288976)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I'm not sure we can answer this without a [mre] ...

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker, I think I have edited it as required now. Would you require a dput of the data too?

Comment: Remove the `+` after `~` in `fmla`.

Comment: Thanks @meriops , I tried that and receive the same error `Error: couldn't evaluate grouping factor houseID within model frame: try adding grouping factor to data frame explicitly if possible`

Comment: Edited again with data @BenBolker

Comment: When you use `weights` with a binomial model, the response is expected to be the proportion of successes; yet the response is binary here. So, what is your `weight` variable supposed to represent?

Comment: The weights here represent the proportion of population living within a particular stratum. When I take them out of the model I am unfortunately still getting the same error @meriops

Comment: `df_var[i]` in your formula brings in the whole vector... To build the formula, your rather want the column name. So with minimal edit of your code, it should read : 
`fmla <- paste0("pred_recent_pf_bin ~ ", names(df_var[i]), " + (1|houseID)")`

Comment: Does each observation of `houseID` have a different value? In other words, does it not actually group any data points? This can be problematic with `glmer`.

Comment: @Dylan_Gomes yes it groups the data points. In the full dataset there are 2489 house IDs, and 10100 observations. The suggestion above worked for me however I have not been able to accept it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: You can ask the user who posted the useful comment to post this comment as an answer, otherwise you won't be able to accept it.

Comment: @meriops your last comment has fixed the issue, would you like to post it as an answer? Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your formula, you don't need "+" after "~", and `df_var[i]` brings in the whole vector where you only want the column name. Your code works if you build the formula with :

```
fmla <- paste0("pred_recent_pf_bin ~ ", names(df_var[i]), " + (1|houseID)")
```